How many clues are sufficient to solve an X-Sudoku puzzle?
I've heard that for standard Sudoku a minimum of 17 clues are needed to solve a puzzle, but I imagine it might be slightly less in the variant X-Sudoku, because I assume there would be slightly fewer options for each cell. Is this true, and if so, how many clues would be sufficient to solve one?

12 cells is the minimum known. Maybe 11 or fewer is possible. https://www.sudokuwiki.org/SudokuX.aspx has a "12 Clue Tough" grid.
